# Order by date when date is string in format is J F Y

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to order query results in MYSQL by date. However the date is not in date format but a VARCHAR in J F Y e.g. 1st January 2020.

I've tried STR_TO_DATE() but that's not worked.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what you tried with `STR_TO_DATE()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the format - `'%D %M %Y'`

```
select str_to_date(yourdatecol,'%D %M %Y')
```

Comment: That worked. Looks like I forgot a table alias in the query. Doh!